How to avoid duplicating fallback in both API responses and useQuery in React Query?
In fetchOrgs, I'm already providing a fallback for items like so:
items: response.data ?? [].
But it seems like TypeScript still thinks data may still be undefined:
const orgs: Org[] | undefined
So this means I have to provide a fallback again:
const {
  data: { items: orgs = [] }, // In here...
} = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['orgs'],
  queryFn: () => fetchOrgs(),
});

const { totalItems: totalOrgs, totalFavs } = useTotal({
  fetchFn: fetchOrgs,
  prefix: 'org',
  items: orgs, // ...so that this is never undefined
});

How can I avoid defining the fallback twice (they are actually many)?
I could do this:
const {
  data,
} = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['orgs'],
  queryFn: () => fetchOrgs(),
});

if (!data) {
  return;
}

const {
  items: orgs,
} = data;

const { totalItems: totalOrgs, totalFavs } = useTotal({
  fetchFn: fetchOrgs,
  prefix: 'org',
  items: orgs,
});

But that would produce this error:

Rendered more hooks than during the previous render


If the data can be undefined, const { data: { items: orgs = [] } } = … would be throwing an exception not assign undefined to orgs. Something else seems wrong here. Can you share a [mcve] please?

The useQuery hook won't do this for you, but it's trivial to make a custom hook that you can use instead.
function useOrgs() {
  const { data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["orgs"],
    queryFn: fetchOrgs,
  });

  return data?.items || [];
}

Now when you execute useOrgs() it always returns an array.
This is probably also a good idea because it ties the query function to the query key, which can be easy to mess up in react query. And this gives you a place where you add custom logic around the query.
See playground

With useQuery you have an initialData !
const { data: todos } = useQuery({
        queryFn: () => getTodos(),
        queryKey: todoKeys.lists(),
        initialData: []
    })

With this your data will not be undefined !
In your example the error is here because your are calling a hook after a condition, in your case the if(!data)
